# How to create DatePicker extension

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I am attempting to move date picker code that attaches to a textfield into an extension. I am struggling with refactoring the @objc code. I am unsure how to reference the textfield and the datepicker within the doneButtonPressed code.

```
extension UIViewController {


    func datePicker(dateValue: UITextField) {

        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(dateDonePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        dateValue.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

        dateValue.inputView = datePicker
    }

    @objc func dateDonePressed() {


        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

        self.dateValue.text = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the future: classes names are capitalised, method/function names lowercased.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add variables in the class:

```
class ViewController {

    var textField: UITextField!
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override var viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        ...// either set up textField here or in the extension
        datePicker.inputView = datePicker

}
extension ViewController {
    func datePicker(dateValue textField: UITextField){
        // if you decided to set the textfield in the extension, then:
        self.textField = textField
    }   
}
```

I don't know who calls `datePicker(dateValue`, but if there is an access to the textfield from there, then probably the text field should have been set and configured from somewhere else.